# modify array element's value with Java MongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to modify array element using Java MongoDB driver. I am able to insert new pair to the array, but can't modify value corresponding to particular key.

How can I increase `a` by 2 in `dummy` array for document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a87614d03a435e4be44bb9"), "dummy" : [ { "a" : 1 }, { "b" : 5 } ] }
```

using Java MongoDB driver?

Here is what I've tried

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id",doc_id_here); 
BasicDBObject incValue = new BasicDBObject("dummy.$.a", 1);
BasicDBObject intModifier = new BasicDBObject("$inc", incValue); 
coll.update(query, intModifier, false, false, WriteConcern.SAFE);
```

Comment: {"_id" : ObjectId("57a87614d03a435e4be44bb9"), "dummy" : [ { "a" : 1 }, { "b" : 5 }

    ]}

Comment: show what have you already tried by adding Java code to your question

Comment: BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
      query.put("_id",doc_id_here);
      BasicDBObject incValue = new BasicDBObject("dummy.$.a", 1); 
      BasicDBObject intModifier = new BasicDBObject("$inc", incValue);
      coll.update(query, intModifier, false, false, WriteConcern.SAFE);

Answer (score 0):

Your query in mongo shell

```
db.collection.update( 
  { "_id": ObjectId("57a87614d03a435e4be44bb9") }, 
  { $inc: { "dummy.$.a": 1 } } 
);
```

will result in error

> The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
>   Unexpanded update: dummy.$.a

because in order to use positional **[`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator for `dummy` array you need to set condition on this array in your query

```
db.collection.update( 
  { "_id": ObjectId("57a87614d03a435e4be44bb9"), "dummy.a": { $exists: true } }, 
  { $inc: { "dummy.$.a": 1 } } 
);
```

and then it will increment `a` as you expect.

With Java MongoDB driver it will be

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", new ObjectId("57a87614d03a435e4be44bb9"));
query.put("dummy.a", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
BasicDBObject incValue = new BasicDBObject("dummy.$.a", 1);
BasicDBObject intModifier = new BasicDBObject("$inc", incValue); 
coll.update(query, intModifier, false, false, WriteConcern.SAFE);
```

**Advice**: before trying to construct your query with Java MongoDB Driver first try if it works in mongo shell.

Comment: i have one more doubt.. suppose key is not exist in array then i want to insert key value.. if key exist then value increment by 1...                             For Example. key "a" exist so i will increment value corresponding to key a by 1. case to key "f" not exist in array so i want insert in dummy array {f:1}

Comment: This is another issue, I am not sure you can complete it with 1 query. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834181/mongodb-insert-document-or-increment-field-if-exists-in-array). If solution with 2 queries (where first query will search document with corresponding key and second query will update your collection according to the result of first) works for you, then update this question or create another one. I am not going to edit your question for the third time, please, do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. i can do it in 2 query but i wanted in one query.. let me check