# MongoDB insert document "or" increment field if exists in array

Tags: mongodb

What I try to do is fairly simple, I have **an array inside a document** ;

```
"tags": [ 
    {
        "t" : "architecture",
        "n" : 12
    }, 
    {
        "t" : "contemporary",
        "n" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "t" : "creative",
        "n" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "t" : "concrete",
        "n" : 3
    }
]
```

I want to push an array of items to array like

```
["architecture","blabladontexist"]
```

If item exists, I want to increment object's `n` value (in this case its `architecture`),

and if don't, add it as a new Item (with value of `n=0`) `{ "t": "blabladontexist", "n":0}`

I have tried `$addToSet`, `$set`, `$inc`, `$upsert: true` with so many combinations and couldn't do it.

How can we do this in MongoDB?

Comment: Have you looked at the aggregation pipeline at all?

Comment: I guess aggregation it`s not solution for the problem, cause it just select data from collection. @Sadettin Bilal Savaş need insert data. It has reason  only if structure of collection will changed.

Comment: Would you consider changing the structure of your data as a solution? For example, you can have references to `Tag` entity IDs in your `tags` array.

Comment: hey josh, ofc its open for a change if theres no other way. I'm just trying to figure out if my question is possible with a single query, because upsert like actions are very common in MongoDB, and I couldn't find a way to do this simple update, what do you mean by tag entity IDs, and how would it help? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With MongoDB 4.2 and newer, the update method can now take a document or [an aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) where the following stages can be used:

1. [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) and its alias [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set)
2. [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and its alias [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#pipe._S_unset)
3. [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot) and its alias [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith).

Armed with the above, your update operation with the aggregate pipeline will be to override the `tags` field by concatenating a filtered `tags` array and a mapped array of the input list with some data lookup in the map:

To start with, the aggregate expression that filters the tags array uses the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and it follows:

```
const myTags = ["architecture", "blabladontexist"];

{ 
    "$filter": { 
        "input": "$tags",
        "cond": { 
            "$not": [
                { "$in": ["$$this.t", myTags] } 
            ] 
        }
    } 
}
```

which produces the filtered array of documents

```
[  
    { "t" : "contemporary", "n" : 2 }, 
    { "t" : "creative", "n" : 1 }, 
    { "t" : "concrete", "n" : 3 }
]
```

Now the second part will be to derive the other array that will be concatenated to the above. This array requires a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) over the `myTags` input array as

```
{ 
    "$map": { 
        "input": myTags,
        "in": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$in": ["$$this", "$tags.t"] },
                "then": { 
                    "t": "$$this", 
                    "n": { 
                        "$sum": [
                            { 
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                    "$tags.n", 
                                    { "$indexOfArray": [ "$tags.t", "$$this" ] } 
                                ] 
                            },
                            1
                        ]
                    } 
                },
                "else": { "t": "$$this", "n": 0 }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The above [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) essentially loops over the input array and checks with each element whether it's in the `tags` array comparing the `t` property, if it exists then the value of the `n` field of the subdocument becomes its current `n` value
expressed with

```
{ 
    "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$tags.n", 
        { "$indexOfArray": [ "$tags.t", "$$this" ] } 
    ] 
}
```

else add the default document with an n value of 0.

Overall, your update operation will be as follows

Your final update operation becomes:

```
const myTags = ["architecture", "blabladontexist"];

db.getCollection('coll').update(
    { "_id": "1234" },
    [
        { "$set": {
            "tags": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                    { "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$tags",
                        "cond": { "$not": [ { "$in": ["$$this.t", myTags] } ] }
                    } },
                    { "$map": { 
                        "input": myTags,
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$in": ["$$this", "$tags.t"] },
                                { "t": "$$this", "n": { 
                                    "$sum": [
                                        { "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$tags.n", 
                                            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$tags.t", "$$this" ] } 
                                        ] },
                                        1
                                    ]
                                } },
                                { "t": "$$this", "n": 0 }
                            ]
                        }
                    } }
                ]
            }
        } }
    ],
    { "upsert": true }
);
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect!! How can you have concatarrays operator in a $set operation in an UPDATE transaction?? Concatarrays is only valid in aggregation pipeline.

Comment: He has a point, because you obviously never ran your final result yourself. It is correct that you can use an aggregation pipeline. BUT you need to wrap the second argument in square brackets [], otherwise it will not know you intend to use an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Additionally, if you run this against a database, even with brackets, the final result will be { "_id" : "1234", "tags" : null } which is not the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible to do in a single command.

MongoDB doesn't allow a $set (or $setOnInsert) and $inc to affect the same field in a single command.

You'll have to do one update command to attempt to $inc the field, and if that doesn't change any documents (n = 0), do the update to  $set the field to it's default value.